# Clarification of summation term in a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

Could someone clarify for me with the summation symbols are needed here?

Aren't $\alpha_h$ and $\beta_k$ enough to construct every element of W?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need the $\sum $ notation because with different  h values you have different $\sin hx $ which can not be added together.

For example $5\sin (5x) +3\sin (3x)$ does not simplify as just one term like $h\sin hx$